# Calculating Covariance in Pandas Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, covariance

Apologies in advance if this is documented somewhere and I just failed to find it:

Let's say that I have a time series data frame that looks like this:

```
WEEK_END_DATE              TITLE_SHORT          SALES  
2012-02-25 00:00:00.000000 "Bob" (EBK)            1
2012-03-31 00:00:00.000000 "Bob" (EBK)            1
2012-03-03 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
2012-03-10 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
2012-03-17 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
2012-04-07 00:00:00.000000 "Sally" (EBK)          1
```

I want to calculate covariance in sales in order to find users that tend to move together. I know that pandas has a covariance feature: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#covariance, but I'm not sure how to reshape my data for this kind of purpose.

Am I correct in thinking that the users need to be set as the column index, so that each series is a vector across the time series? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: What does your "move together" mean? Does it mean go in the same 'WEEK_END_DATE'?

Comment: I think by "move together" he means they "co-vary", i.e. OP is using covariance as a measure of correlation (instead of actually calculating correlation).

Comment: It means the general shape of purchases is the same for Sally and Bob. Another example would be stocks-- Google stocks tend to move together, either up or down, with greater correspondence to Apple stocks than to   General Electric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot wasn't quite right, but this worked:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, rows='WEEK_END_DATE', cols='TITLE_SHORT', values='SALES', aggfunc="sum")
```

I'm not sure what the difference was.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for pandas [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html). First do:

```
df.pivot(index='WEEK_END_DATE', columns='TITLE_SHORT', values='SALES')
```

and you should get Bob and Sally as columns. Then you can just do normal correlation analysis with this two columns.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I forgot about pivot tables